# Stop foldmarker inserting hash

Tags: folding, filetype, comments, fold-marker

I my folds are set with `foldmarker={{{,}}}`. When I create a fold it inserts a comment `#` char before the marker. So it inserts `#{{{`. How do I stop it doing this?

I have syntax highlighting (and it seems therefore also filetype) set to bash. But it's not a bash file. It's just a text file and I'm using bash highlighting for convenience of viewing numbers, quotes and so on. I can see the sense of it inserting a comment char before the marker if it was a bash script. But it's not...

It would actually be nice to have it insert a couple of spaces instead (and if it would do that courtesy in any case).

Comment: `:set cms=` or `:set cms=\ \ \ \ `. Read `:h cms`.